# Do documents get encrypted before being transmitted to DocuSign?

Tags: encryption, docusignapi

I have a fairly generic question, whose answer I couldn't find in the API references.
When I send a document to DocuSign (using either SOAP/REST), do the contents get encrypted before being transmitted?
I know that the document goes over a HTTPS connection, but I wanted to know if there is any encryption happening **before** the document goes over the wire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the transport (HTTPS) is encrypted. You will be providing the raw PDF bytes in base64 encoding for either REST or SOAP. If you were to encrypt the PDF before sending to DS then they would need a way to decrypt it.

Comment: Yes, that's a nice point. Encrypting the document would create a need on the DocuSign server side to decrypt, which would create the need for a key exchange of some sort, on top of the key exchange that would happen in the SSL handshake. Thanks!